# My Lex code receiving segmentation fault (core dump) at line *yy_cp = yy_hold_char

Tags: parsing, segmentation-fault, yacc, lex, coredump

Here a snippet of generated .c code from .Lex.
And the Coredump is coming at the very first Iteration

```
while (1)   /* loops until end-of-file is reached */{
   yy_cp = yy_c_buf_p;

    /* Support of yytext. */
    *yy_cp = yy_hold_char;   // receiving coredump here

    /* yy_bp points to the position in yy_ch_buf of the start of
     * the current run.*/

     yy_bp = yy_cp;
     yy_current_state = yy_start;}
```

[Here you can find code](https://gist.github.com/mohakhan/bc4dff99ce1c5d742ff0#file-lex-lex)

Comment: Please let me know If you people need some more inputs

Comment: The obvious question is,  why do you think yy_c_buf_p is valid?

Comment: Presumably you've managed to avoid initializing the flex buffer. Please show your actual code, not the generated code.

Comment: @rici : Please find the code here [link]https://gist.github.com/mohakhan/bc4dff99ce1c5d742ff0#file-lex-lex

Comment: @mik: Lots of questionable stuff there, but nothing which should lead to a segfault. Why are you defining `YYLMAX`? That has not effect unless you specify `%array`, which as far as I can see you do not do and which is rarely a good idea. Are you invoking flex with `-l`? And with what other options?

Comment: @rici : frankly speaking I don't have to much idea about Lex and Yaac. I am working on a legacy code written in 1990.
For your information I am compiling lex without any option ( lex fileName.l)

Comment: @mik: ok, the generated code snippet looks like an old version of flex, but it's possible that invoking it as `lex` adds the lex-compatibility flag. Anyway, I don't see anything which would cause `yy_c_buf_p` to be wrong in your lex file, but it might be elsewhere. (And, of course, a memory corruption bug could be almost anywhere.)

Comment: @IraBaxter : Yes I am comparing this buff values from other. And for my code it is '0' (NULL).
How to identify? and what chages required correct initialization of yy_c_buf_p ?

Comment: @IraBaxter: In very First Iteration of while (1):
For other code :
yy_hold_char =  ^@ 
yy_c_buf_p    =  312015256

But For this problematic code :
yy_hold_char =  ^@ 
yy_c_buf_p    =  0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answer of my own question. Here are some explanation of Solution

1. I have two .Lex (Type1_Lex.l & Type2_Lex.l)and two .Yacc (Type1_Yacc.y & Type2_Yacc.y) code
2. I am compiling all and relevant .c (Type1_Lex.c, Type2_Lex.c, Type1_Yacc.c & Type2_Yacc.v) and .h files are getting generated
3. And further compilation of .c with  generates Type1_Lex.o, Type2_Lex.o, Type1_Yacc.o Type2_Yacc.o
4. Further I am putting all these object files in a single .a

**The Problems are Here**

5. ...
   ld: Warning: size of symbol `**yy_create_buffer**' changed from 318 in libuperbe.a(**TYPE1_Lex**.o) to 208 in libxxx.a (**TYPE2_Lex**.o)

ld: Warning: size of symbol `**yy_load_buffer_state**' changed from 262 in libuperbe.a(**TYPE1_Lex**.o) to 146 in libxxx.a(**TYPE2_Lex**.o)

ld: Warning: size of symbol `**yy_init_buffer**' changed from 278 in libuperbe.a(**TYPE1_Lex**.o) to 164 in libxxx.a(**TYPE2_Lex**.o)

*Some symbols are same in both generated .c (TYPE1_Lex.c & TYPE2_Lex.c)*

- When both object file bind in a single .a the similar
  (yy_create_buffer,yy_init_buffer,yy_load_buffer_state) symbols got
  **overridden**.
- At the runtime when the methods yy_create_buffer(),yy_init_buffer(), yy_load_buffer_state() should be called defined in TYPE2_Lex.c **but in actual those methods are called from the file TYPE1_Lex.c** and the leads to the memory corruption some how.
- For moving ahead I decided to use **sed** with following patterns :

**Sed TYPE2_Lex.c with :**

- s/yy_create_buffer()/TYPE1_create_buffer/g
- s/yy_init_buffer()/TYPE1_init_buffer/g
- s/yy_load_buffer_state()/TYPE1_load_buffer_state/g

**Sed TYPE2_Lex.c with**

- s/yy_create_buffer()/TYPE2_create_buffer/g
- s/yy_init_buffer()/TYPE2_init_buffer/g
- s/yy_load_buffer_state()/TYPE2_load_buffer_state/g

**So that the Loader can easily differentiate the symbol. And at the run time confusion between the methods name become null**.

After all these Step I am able to move ahead :)
***Thanks all for your help :)***

Comment: You should have mentioned this useful fact in your question. Anyway, you can change the prefix in generated code. For flex, use the flag `-PTYPE1` (or, in recent versions, `--prefix=TYPE1`) to change the prefix to `TYPE1`. For bison, use the flag `-pTYPE1` (or, in recent versions, `-Dapi.prefix=TYPE1`).

Comment: @rici : I was not aware about such thing as I am very new for .Lex and .Yacc and your will help me further in learning the these Technologies.